# Is this weird solitaire card game a real game or just a multi-generational prank?

Tags: probability, card-games

I have a question about a weird, unknown (and possibly impossible) game a friend of mine has taught me.
It is a solitaire game that's played with a regular deck of 52 cards but it is suspiciously difficult to beat. What's more, neither my friend nor I were able to find ANY reference to it in all the Internets.

I am aware that the question is not necessarily interesting to anyone but my friend and I, but I was wondering if someone would be willing to help me calculate the odds of beating this game? I think it would help us decide if this is a real game or if it's just a weird multi-generational prank my friend's father (who taught him the game) is pulling.
My current grasp of math and probability does not allow me to undertake the project alone.

Here are the rules:

> Nine columns of three overlapping face up cards are laid on the table.
> Cards are played one by one, face up, on each columns from left to right, without skipping any column.

> The face value of each card is used to calculate a sum with the two closest cards (either on top or on bottom) on the column and the last card can "wrap" with the bottom card (the first one played on the column) to achieve a certain sum if needed. face cards all are worth 10 points.

> If a card is revealed and can either sum up to 9, 19, or 29, the three cards are taken from the column and placed under the deck. If all the cards of a column are thus picked up, the column is eliminated.

> The *theoretical* goal is to pick up all nine columns before the deck runs out. If the deck does run out, it's game over.

Now... my friend has played thousands of games and has **never** beat the game even once. He holds on to it only because his own father boasts that he finished it twice in thirty years of playing it... But it really sounds fishy.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The [Board & Card Games StackExchange](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com) may be a better place for this question. (Maybe someone there can at least identify it.) That said, I wouldn't consider this a "game", since the player seems to have no agency; this is more like an extended coin flip that either works or doesn't.

Comment: Are you saying in each turn you go to the "next" column (cyclically), place a card from the deck on the top of that column, and then, in the same column, you look for potentially three cards one after another (or two at the top and one at the bottom) which make up $9$, $19$ or $29$, then, if found, remove those cards and put them at the bottom of the deck, in the same order?

Comment: Depending on the deck's starting arrangement, this game either ends in a win or loss, *or it never ends*. In a sample of 10^8 simulated games, there were 153 wins, 99999228 losses, and 619 "nonstoppers". Examples: (1) The deck [9,7,10,6,10,3,3,1,4,10,10,10,2,8,8,4,5,7,6,9,10,4,2,1,8,10,5,10,10,2,3,1,5,10,1,6,10,10,8,10,6,7,3,4,9,2,10,5,10,7,10,9] gives a win in $45$ plays. (2) With deck [9,10,6,4,5,10,10,1,1,8,5,6,9,7,10,10,3,6,10,3,4,7,10,8,2,8,3,5,10,10,4,10,9,10,7,6,9,2,10,10,2,10,8,2,10,5,3,7,1,10,1,4] the game enters, after 156 plays, an infinite cycle with a repeating period of 51 plays.

Comment: @Blue Thank you! I didn't even know this board existed!

Comment: @StinkingBishop Exactly! (Sorry if my original explanation wasn't clear enough, English is not my first language.)

Comment: @r.e.s. Ok WOW? I mean, your numbers FEEL right and I'm super impressed that you were able to run a simulation of the game. If it's not too much to ask: how did you do that?!

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeSt-Laurent An assumption I made in my simulation is this: after placing card $e$ (say) on a column, if the column is $(ab..cde),$ then the only cards removed will be the first *one* of the three triplets $cde$, $dea$, or $eab$ (in that order) having a sum ending in 9 (if any of them do). Also, the stated ordering is preserved when the triplet is added to the bottom of the deck. (Interestingly, the probability of winning almost doubles if the removed triplet is added in *random* order to the bottom of the deck.)

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeSt-Laurent If you post your question at the linked site, I would be happy to post an answer there that would include the simulation program.

Comment: @r.e.s. I will GLADLY post my question on the Board & Card Games board. I will add the wording Stinking Bishop has formulated.

To answer your questions, other triplets revealed by the removal of a valid triplet will be removed from a column before playing the card on the next column. Also, the triplet's order is indeed preserved when added to the bottom of the deck.

I'm genuinely in awe! Thank you again!!!

Comment: (This question is now posted at [Board & Card Games StackExchange](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/56814/37619).)